# Cannot change wallpaper on Xiaomi devices

Tags: xiaomi, wallpaper

Since the last update on my MI 11 Lite 5G, I'm unable to set my wallpaper to one of my own photos. The only choices given are supplied wallpapers - there is no longer a 'Local' or 'Gallery' option.

Does anyone know if the option is now available somewhere else, or have they blundered on this release?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it. I found the photo I wanted in my photo gallery and hit 'more', then chose 'set as wallpaper'.